Reference Request: Complement of K is connected iff K is simply connected where K is locally connected
Hello Hello everybody,
I am currently looking for a reference, which I simply cannot find unfortunally. In the question:
Reverse of Jordan curve theorem
it was claimed that if $K \subseteq \mathbb C$ is connected, compact and especially locally connected then the following are equivalent:

$\mathbb C \setminus K$ is connected.
$K$ is simply connected.

I tried to look for a reference but could not find any. Does somebody know any reference?
